# Rails: Using form_for multiple times (DOM ids)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I would like to use the form_for helper multiple times for the same model in the same page. But the input fields use the same ID attribute (in the HTML), so clicking on the label of a field in another form will select the same input in the first form.

Is there a solution besides settings all attributes manually via :for => "title_#{item.id}" and :id => "title_#{item.id}"?

Using Rails 3.0.9

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `:namespace => 'some_unique_prefix'` option. In contrast to `:index`, this will not change the value used in the `name` attribute.

It's also possible to use an array, e.g. when you have nested forms or different forms that happen to have some fields in common: `:namespace => [@product.id, tag.id]` or `:namespace => [:product, @product.id]`

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that this only works in Rails 3.2 and up.

Comment: Maybe this is not obviously, but :namespace is to be used in form_for. For example: `form_for :user, :url => user_session_path, :html => { :class => 'form-inline' }, :namespace => 'quick' do |f|`

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer myself, one can pass a :index option to form_for. That string will be used in the id and for attributes:

```
<%= form_for @person, :index => @person.id do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

will parse

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/person/11" class="edit_person" id="edit_person_11" method="post">
  <!-- Hidden div for csrf removed -->
<label for="person_11_name">Name</label> 
<input id="person_11_name" name="person[11][name]" size="30" type="text" /> 
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Person" /> 
</form>
```

Notice it'll change the name of the inputs as well.

Answer (score -6):

I believe you can add this param:

```
:html => { :id => 'id_i_want' }
```

Comment: That will change the id of the form itself, not the inputs.