# Trying to add a comment section, get: Couldn't find Post without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a newsfeed like feature on my page, where it shows all posts created by the people you follow. Much like Facebook, I would like users to be able to comment straight from the newsfeed, underneath the post.

This is probably an easy fix, but I haven't been able to figure out the best way, or even how to get the post_id.

My current **newsfeeds/index.html.erb** looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <li> <%= image_tag(activity.owner.avatar.url(:thumb), height: "64", width: "64") %>  <%= activity.owner.fullname %>
   <ul>
    <li><strong><%= activity.trackable.title %></strong></li>
    <li><%= activity.trackable.content %></li>
     <ul>
       <li><%= render 'comments/form' %></li>
     </ul>
   </ul>
 </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

The **comments/_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
 <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
<% end %>
```

Then we have the controllers:

**newsfeeds_controller.rb**

```
def index
 @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids, owner_type: "User")
 @comment = Comment.new
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :load_post

def create
 @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
 @comment.user = current_user
 if @comment.save
   @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
   redirect_to @post, notice: "Comment was created."
 else
   render :new
 end
end
....
 def load_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 end
end
```

So my question is how do I fix it so that I store the post_id and that it finds it?

Comment: You haven't shown us how `PublicActivity::Activity` relates to a `Post`. It sounds like from the feed you may not even have a Post model? In which case you either need to be able to derive it from the object you do have and use that in the `form_for` or something like that.

Comment: That's from the PublicActivity gem. I do have a Post model. Which works and displays the data. In the post.rb model I have :

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }
  
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

Comment: What I see on the error page is that it doesn't even get the ID. So it's not failing. The problem is I am not giving it the post_id. Problem is how do I make it so that I can get the :id of the post you are commenting on, into the post_id...

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the comment form seems to do a post request to a nested route (i.e. /posts/:post_id/comments). The post_id would then be retrieved from the url in the CommentsController.

The current 'comments/_form.html.erb' partial requires the @post variable to be able to generate the right action url (@post variable doesn't seem to be set anywhere in this case).

To solve this you *could* pass 'post' as a local variable to the form partial. That way your form partial would be able to create the right url and your controller would have access to the post_id.

See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables

newsfeeds/index.html.erb:

```
<ul>
 <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
 <li> <%= image_tag(activity.owner.avatar.url(:thumb), height: "64", width: "64") %>  <%= activity.owner.fullname %>
   <ul>
    <li><strong><%= activity.trackable.title %></strong></li>
    <li><%= activity.trackable.content %></li>
     <ul>
       <li><%= render 'comments/form', post: activity.trackable %></li>
     </ul>
   </ul>
 </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

comments/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [post, @comment] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
 <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
<% end %>
```

(There may be cleaner ways to implement this)

To add a nested route, edit 'config/routes.rb'

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

PS:
When rendering the same form multiple times on the same page, the DOM id would be the same for all forms and their input fields. To avoid this you should probably set the namespace-option in the form_for call (see this question: [Rails: Using form_for multiple times (DOM ids)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427990/rails-using-form-for-multiple-times-dom-ids#answer-6506682))

comments/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [post, @comment], namespace: post.id do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
 <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried to apply the changes you suggested but got this error undefined method `post_comments_path'

Comment: Please provide the output of 'rake routes' or content of routes.rb.

Comment: here you go: 
  resources :friendships
  resources :posts
  resources :comments 
  resources :newsfeeds

  devise_for :users

  root 'staticpages#index'

  get 'profile/' => 'profiles#index'
  get 'profile/:id' => 'profiles#show'
  get 'feed' => 'newsfeeds#index'
  get 'notificatios' => 'notifications#index'
  get 'comment' => 'comments#new'
  get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#shows'

Comment: Try changing 'resources posts' to 'resources :posts do
      resources :comments, only: :create
    end'

Comment: Hmm progress it seems. Previously the error redirect me to /comments now it goes to posts/:id/comments. 

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lNOQ3TjDsJWYupcRn9lB4ca07WX8cpPpWib/qhjGwNI=", "comment"=>{"24"=>{"content"=>"ok"}}, "commit"=>"Add comment", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"comments", "post_id"=>"24"}

and it seems like we are now able to get get the post_id.. yet I still get: Couldn't find Post without an ID

Comment: Hmm. Seems that the index option in the form_for call gives you a problem in params[:comments], this can be solved by using the namespace option instead of index option it seems. Not sure if this is the problem though.