# How do I use a hidden_field_tag to help create a valid object in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a prayer website with the ability to comment on a public prayer. When I try to create a comment on a prayer, it returns four errors:

- Prayer must exist
- User must exist
- User can't be blank
- Prayer can't be blank

And then every comment creation form on the page is automatically filled in with the text I put in the first comment box, and all of them have the same 4 errors on them. I tried to use the hidden_field_tag to put in the comment form for the right user id and prayer id but they aren't put into the hash for the new comment object, they are separate.

This is the debug stuff at the bottom of the page:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"abcdefg", "comment"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"content"=>"Comment comment 1 2 3"} permitted: false>, "user_id"=>"1", "prayer_id"=>"301", "commit"=>"Comment", "controller"=>"comments", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

```rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @prayer = current_user.prayers.build
      @comment = current_user.comments.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
end
```

controllers/comments_controller.rb

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def create
    @comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'static_pages/home', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Comment deleted"
    redirect_back_or_to( root_url, status: :see_other )
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :prayer_id, :user_id)
    end

    def correct_user
      @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url, status: :see_other if @comment.nil?
    end
end
```

models/comment.rb

```rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :prayer
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order( created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :prayer_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<li id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(comment.user, size: 30), comment.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %></span>
  <span class="comment-content"><%= comment.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
      <%= link_to "delete comment", comment, data: { "turbo-method": :delete,
                                            "turbo-confirm": "Are you sure?"} %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

views/prayers/_prayer.html.erb

```
<li id="prayer-<%= prayer.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(prayer.user, size: 50), prayer.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to prayer.user.name, prayer.user %></span>
  <span class="content">
    <%= prayer.content %>
    <% if prayer.image.attached? %>
      <%= image_tag prayer.image.variant(:display) %>
    <% end %>
  </span>

  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(prayer.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if current_user?(prayer.user) %>
      <%= link_to "delete", prayer, data: { "turbo-method": :delete,
                                            "turbo-confirm": "Are you sure?"} %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <span>
    <%= render 'shared/comment_form', prayer_id: prayer.id %>
  </span>
  <span>
    <% if prayer.comments.any? %>
      <ol class="comments">
      <% prayer.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <%= render comment %>
      <% end %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

- ** views/shared/_comment_form.html.erb * **

```
<%= form_with(model: @comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <center>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area(:content, placeholder: "Comment on this prayer...") %>
    </div>
    <div><%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %></div>
    <div><%= hidden_field_tag :prayer_id, prayer_id %></div>
      <%= f.submit "Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </center>
<% end %>
```

views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object != nil && object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

views/shared/_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="prayers">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items,
                    params: { controller: :static_pages, action: :home } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: First thing I see is that in your comment form you use `hidden_field_tag` instead of `f.hidden_field` then your hidden comments may not be linked to your `@comment` record passed as the model of the form. Usually `*_field_tag` elements are used in forms not linked to any model..

Comment: your hidden fields* sorry

Comment: Thank you! That worked! However, the error for not entering content into the comment form still shows up on every form on the page and not just the one I clicked "Comment" on

Comment: In the comments controller, create action add a bang to save : `if @comment.save!` you may get more information. Also I don't usually use parenthesis as in the comment form, but I doubt this is the problem..

Comment: Oops sorry I didn't answer your question. I was focused on the `permitted: false>` in your logs. Maybe what you can do is that instead to create your `@comment` record in the controller, just replace `model: @comment` in the form by `model: Comment.new`. But I am not sure it will fix.

Comment: If my solution doesn't help, you may check those threads : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214845/multiple-forms-for-the-same-model-in-a-single-page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427990/rails-using-form-for-multiple-times-dom-ids though one solution is to add an index to your forms. But because your comment record is new for every of the forms (not persisted), there will be no id. Then just disregard this solution. (or tweak it to your tune, maybe using the original prayer id...) Ideally your model should be a composite : `[@prayer, Comment.new]` and adapting your routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Maxence, I discovered I need to use `f.hidden_field` versus `hidden_field_tag`

so I changed the views/shared/_comment_form.html.erb to the following:

```
<%= form_with(model: @comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <center>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area(:content, placeholder: "Comment on this prayer...") %>
    </div>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %></div>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :prayer_id, value: prayer_id %></div>
      <%= f.submit "Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </center>
<% end %>
```